# Add a bar where you can see how many answers have been given

Tags: feature-request

Whenever you open a post in Mathstack, you can not know how many answer that post has got. To know you need to scroll down to the end of the post. In general when I see a post I how long is the scroll bar, to predict if the question has got an answer or not. **But sometimes** OP post very long question, so this prediction does not work every time(Although it is a prediction!).

My suggestion is in the right top side where stat of the post shows(i.e. asked and viewed part), another bar where you can see **how many answer has been given and any answer accepted or not**.

I suggest this because when you refresh new question page you do not expect to open every single at the same time. You open a post, you see the problem, you are interested, you scroll down, otherwise, go for next post. Meanwhile people may have answer your next favourite post. When you open it, you see that it has been answered by someone already. If the post is very long sometimes reading the whole question, you see that 9 or 10 answers has been posted. So to avoid that you need to remember everytime scroll down first.

This is just a suggestion. Just adding one bar would make things more simple and easy to use too. That's all.

Comment: The number of answers is visible before you click on the post (on the left, with the number of votes and views); the color of the box is even different if an answer has been accepted.  Do you mean that this is not sufficient for the way you use the site?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon that I explained in in 3rd paragraph. A post you see now will go to page two in 10 minutes when you refresh the page. So if you may think that you must see the post after what you are watching at that time. Meanwhile...

Comment: Is scrolling down really such a burden?

Comment: @tilper No, but you need remember that everytime to scroll down. A webpage is where things are easily accessible. I said it because the webpage would become more easily accessible than before!

Comment: I wish there was a way to distinguish between downvotes that mean "A change like this would make the site worse" and the downvotes that mean "We can make due with what we have, so we shouldn't bother trying to improve anything" and the downvotes that mean "Not having tried it, I don't think I'd find it useful, and therefore nobody else will find it useful either".

Answer (score 5):

Between the comments on the questions and the answers itself, this thing literally exists.

The number of answers, and you can choose how to order them. Moreover, if there is an accepted answer, it will appear first (with an exception for when the answer was posted by the author of the question, in which case it might not appear first).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes: "Whenever you open a post" you will have first clicked on the post in order to open it.

But every question listed on the main page (from which you open a post) *already shows* the net votes the question has earned thus far, the number of answers received, and when the number of answers received is green, that means that the question has an answer.

And you'll also see the number of views the question has received up to that point.

Look to the left column which sits to the left of the questions:

[image]